# ASP.NET Publishing Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, ftp

I'm trying to publish my project to given host. I have only ftp access and publishing from Visual Studio. It says succesfully published. But when i try to access it says

The page cannot be found

The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be caused by several reasons.

1. The publish may not be successful.
2. Your request file is excluded from the project so it won't be copied with other files.
3. Your request URL is incorrect.
4. The logic which handles your request may returns an 404 response which defined by developer.

You better check the file status on your published server to decide which is the reason. Or can you access other pages via browser of your published web site?

Comment: all of them succesfully uploaded... and i can not access any page which are wants to access db.

Comment: Can you access other pages successfully or all of them returns 404? Can you add some log in your page handler to see whether your request enters the page handler?

Comment: i can access pages which are not connecting to db. How can i add some log? I know file operations and logging but i'm new with asp.net...

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAK, You can use any log framework like http://logging.apache.org/log4net/. They are easy to use. For your case, check whether the db connection config is right. Maybe the 404 returns from the db connection and throw directly on page. You can use try catch clause around your db connection code and use log to see whether the connection is correct.